# How to set server.address from os env vars to java spring boot properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Have a simple Spring Boot project and specific properties file with this content:

```
server:
  address: ${SERVER_HOST}
  port: ${SERVER_PORT}
```

The env vars are set from OS from the service, but `server.address` in Spring Boot is `java.net.InetAddress`:

```
Failed to bind properties under 'server.address' to java.net.InetAddress:

    Property: server.address
    Value: "${SERVER_HOST}"
    Origin: class path resource [config/application.yaml] - 20:12
    Reason: failed to convert java.lang.String to java.net.InetAddress (caused by java.net.UnknownHostException: ${SERVER_HOST})
```

My environment is:

```bash
SERVER_HOST=127.0.0.1
SERVER_PORT=8080
```

How to transform the String value to `InetAddress` in property file? or where is the correct way to set this value?

Answer (score 0):

Guess that your environment variable is not configured property and so it is actually parsing `${SERVER_HOST}` rather than `127.0.0.1`.  You can use the command `printenv` (in case of linux and macOS) to verify what are the actual value of the environment variables to see if they are really configured or not.

Comment: I import the env vars using `source .env` command, but you're right, the vars are not exported, are local only, for test vars i use `echo $FOO` but in `printenv` are not show.

Comment: ok so after you export the vars property , does it work now ?